# use BroadcastReceiver or whatsoever to receive and watch a File readout changes

Tags: android, file, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

There are some files in android , that the kernel or Android OS changes their readout ...

A small example for that , in dual or quad core android phones , they have a file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online  , when the second core is running and enabled , it reads out the value "1" , when it is disabled (sometimes the kernel disables the 2nd core when the screen is off) the file reads out the value "0" ...

So my question , how can I setup a Broadcast Receiver or whatever that can do this job , to watch the file's readout changes , and does something once the file changes (more like the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive ) ?

Comment: you can use file observer

Comment: Would you please write your answer in the answers section and explain a bit more ?